# Can Axis2 Client consume a non Axis SOAP Server ( CXF server )?

Tags: java, soap, cxf, axis

I have a SOAP server that is developed with Apache CXF, my question can a client developed with Axis2 consume this service without any compatibility issues ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Yes, there are no problems. 
The only problem may be the implementation of certificate security, WS-Security. 
In any case there are always solutions for everything, I have business experience with communications between Axis2 and CXF.

Comment: thank you @AlbertoPérez